# How can I destroy a specific Terraform managed resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-dms

I have a DMS task that failed and isn't resuming or restarting.  Unfortunately, according to AWS Support, the only recourse is to destroy and recreate it.  I have a large infrastructure that takes several hours to destroy and recreate with Terraform.  I'm running Terraform version 1.2.X with the AWS provider version 4.17.0.

I tried running `terraform plan -destroy -target="<insert resource_type>.<insert resource_name>"`.  I tried with and without quotes, double hyphens prior to the `target` option, module names, etc. Every time the result comes back with this error:

> Either you have not created any objects yet or the existing objects were...

My hierarchy is this: Main module -> sub module -> resource. My spelling and punctuation are correct.

I've Google it.  I find only the Hashicorp documentation that specifies the syntax but not the naming convention, as well as bug reports from years ago.  How do I selectively destroy a resource?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out I wasn't naming my resource correctly.

After some trial and error, I ran a destroy plan for my entire infrastructure (`terraform plan <insert module runtime params> -destroy`).  Using the output from that, I found the name of the resource I wanted to destroy.  The format was `module.<submodule>.<resourcetype>.<resourcename>`.

Once I acquired the resource name directly from Terraform, I first ran the `terraform plan -destroy -target="module.<submodule>.<resourcetype>.<resourcename>"` command to verify the outcome, then the `terraform destroy -target="module.<submodule>.<resourcetype>.<resourcename>"` command and it worked!

Comment: I had a similar problem.  In my case the name of the resource was: module.ec2_instance_postgres["1"].aws_instance.this[0].  I had to escape the quotes around "1" (i.e. terraform destroy --target=module.ec2_instance_postgres[\"1\"].aws_instance.this[0])